# Removing the last node from Complete Binary Tree

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Every node in a Complete Binary Tree can be identified by its label. In other words, a level order traversal of the CBT means accessing nodes in the ascending order of labels. I wrote a function getPointer to return the node given the Root and the Label. For example in the complete binary tree shown below, the **key 5** has the **label 4**, the key 38 has label 3 and so on.

> ```
>      1 
>    /   \
>   2     38
>  /
> 5
> ```

Where I am going wrong in the following approach? 
I have node structure.

```
node 
{
  rightChild
  leftChild
  value
  label
}
```

C-styled Pseudocode :

```
     getPointer(root, label)
     if(label == 1) return root
     else
     {
        temp_node = getPointer(root,label/2);
        child     = temp_node->left;
        if(label == child->label) return child;
        else                      return temp_node->right;
     }
```

Comment: Other than handling potentially NULL children if the label they ask for is too big, your pseudo code looks sound to me.

Comment: You might want to think about how you could convert the tree into a different structure offering fast access to this information, but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code does not handle following scenario:

```
     1
    / \
   2   38
        \
         5
```

You can simply apply BFS for this problem.

Comment: this is a complete Binary Tree. Also level order traversal means BFS.

Comment: Oh I missed that part :D. But still BFS can be applied. In your code, apart from a null check for child, it looks good.

Comment: it is segFaulting, gdb is not helping.

Comment: Try iterative level order traversal using queue.

Comment: @envy_intelligence, when you are getting segfaults in your C code, you should consider either using something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/boundschecking/ or rewriting your code in a safe language (Java, C#, Pascal, Python, Haskell, Scheme, ML, etc.), debugging it there, and then translating back.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be checking if your root is a null ptr. There could be a case when the level is not 1, but you are passing a null ptr to your methods. For example, if during recursion, when the right child is null.